# SQL Server Join columns with wildcard

Tags: sql-server, join

I need to find a way to join two tables based using the columns' names with wild cards. This is the scenario I have:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
AuthCode varchar(10)

)

INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES ('52201')

SELECT * FROM #table1

JOIN bilact
ON #table1.AuthCode = bilact.byAuthCode
```

In bilact table, the auth code is 005221 (the field is a varchar) and when I run the above query, it does not return any result.

The situation I am running into is so complicated and i do not want to explain why I must do it this way cause it is the only way that will work. Is there a way I can add the wild card with the column name in a join? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to search within the column using a wildcard ? Or do you want to join to any columns whose name match a wildcard pattern?

Comment: It is a column in the bilact table that stores auth codes as varchars.

Comment: Wait, you are entering '52201' in a `varchar` column, have '005221' in another `varchar` column and want to match them approximately?

Comment: Thank you for asking Simon, I will go with search if it is easier! How would I write the Where statement that compares two columns with wildcards? Where AuthCode = byAuthCode?

Comment: Are you looking to join on two tables where one column is a substring of another. Neither of those strings matches the other as a substring, rather they share the characters 522. Are you trying to match on two columns that share a substring? Or one that is a substring of another?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want one column to be the substring of another:

`SELECT * FROM #table1
JOIN bilact
ON str(bilact.byAuthCode) LIKE '%' + #table1.AuthCode + '%'`

or, if you need to match a substring in either table

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #table1
JOIN bilact
ON str(bilact.byAuthCode) LIKE '%' + #table1.AuthCode + '%'
OR #table1.byAuthCode LIKE '%' + str(bilact.AuthCode) + '%'`

You can remove the str()'s if both columns are varchars or some form of string field.

Otherwise, you need to decide what the longest common substring the 2 columns need in common, and in the join, iterate over every possible substring of one of the columns and do a like as above with the other column against it.

Comment: This has some additional information on the performance implications of this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019557/join-sql-server-tables-on-a-like-statement

Comment: Yeah, it's not fast. If you can restrict the wildcard to only the end, that's a lot faster.

Comment: But I don't want to second guess his requirements

Comment: BTW, neither of these gave me any results when I tried it here: http://rextester.com/RUI55926

Comment: Well @shree.pat18 you are inserting into the same table twice in that example. Plus I am unsure of his requirements, as I presumed one was a substring of the other, but not from that example above, I realized I miss-read it.

Comment: Sorry, got it wrong that time, but still no results: http://rextester.com/LWGEA77677

Comment: @shree.pat18 following your example I realized that one is not a substring of another. That is why it does not work. Thus I am unsure as to what they want it to do. If one is a substring (change '52201' to '5221') then above will work. If you want to match two columns that have matching substrings, then I would join on a single char match.